# How can I merge a git branch so that topic commits are orphaned?

Tags: git

I'm still coming up to speed with some of the more advanced features of Git...

Given the following history, how can I clean up topic branch merges so they appear in history as a single commit?

```
[master] - - - - - - - C - - -
   \
   [feature] - A - - B - - D -
```

Ideally, I'd like to rebase [feature] with [master] at D and then merge [feature] into [master], leaving A and B orphaned.

I thought I could do this simply by:

```
$ git rebase master # on feature branch
$ git co master
$ git merge --no-ff feature
```

and then clean up the orphaned commits with

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

That still leaves A and B in the history though - Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "fuse" A, B and D, you can use an interactive rebase.

If your branch `feature` is on top of `master` (which it will be after you have issued `git rebase master` on this branch), do:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Then, in the file which will open in an editor, replace the `pick` on commits A and B with `squash`. Git will then squash A and B into D, and an editor will pop with the commit messages for all squashed commits.

Answer (score 3):

If I redraw your diagrams to place the branch markers at the tip of the branch (which reflects the actual representation of branches) your original situation is:

```
o --- C (master)
 \
   --- A --- B --- D (feature)
```

And after rebasing and merging with `--no-ff` as you describe, you now have:

```
o --- C ------------------ M (master)
 \      \                 /
  \       A' --- B' --- D' (feature)
   \
    --- A --- B --- D
```

As I understand it, you now want to make sure that `A`, `B` and `D` disappear from your repository.  Firstly, I would say that I strongly recommend that you don't worry about these commits.

However, if you really want to get rid of them, then you will have to make sure that they are truly unreachable, or `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` will not remove them.  As it is, they will still be pointed to (at least) by the reflog for `feature`.  There are various ways of expiring entries from the reflog, e.g. with:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now feature
```

... or a safer option should be to set [the config variable](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) `gc.reflogexpireunreachable` to `now` and expire the reflog:

```
git config gc.reflogexpireunreachable
git reflog expire feature
```

In either case, you would then need to run `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` afterwards again.

However, to reiterate what I said above, I wouldn't do this - those commits aren't hurting anyone and the reflog is a valuable safety net when using git.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and explaination

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collapse the effect of a branch into a single commit, then from master do:

```
git merge --squash feature
git commit
```

although IMHO being able to keep the individual commits on the branch intact is actually a good feature most of the time.

Alternatively, you could use `git rebase -i` on the branch and tell it to squash all the commits together, and then merge the squashed result onto master.

Comment: Please, remove one of your answers. They are moslty the same!

Answer (score 0):

Why would it remove A and B?

The `git rebase master` will make feature to be branched off the tip of master and when you commit, all the commits from feature will come to master. Thus you will see A and B ( actually A' and B')

And `git gc` doesn't have anything to do with what you see in the history. It removes dangling commits ( which can be A and B, but you have A' and B' in master now)

If you want them to come as single commit, try the `--no-commit` option or look at other alternatives like `git rebase -i` ( and squash)